# Scala and SBT setup

Tags: scala

I installed scala and sbt. I would like to know how to tell sbt to use the existing scala I have installed because what I have noticed is that when I run sbt console it tries to download scala again and other packages.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the docs: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/scala.html#local

Add this to your `build.sbt`:

```
 scalaVersion := "2.10.0-local"

 scalaHome := Some(file("/path/to/scala/home/"))
```

**Edit**:

Oh, and I'd recommend @0__'s suggestion.  Just go with the default `sbt` way of letting sbt manage per-project scala versions: It is smart and will not download the same version twice, sharing versions between projects. It's worth the disk space used, and lets you shared your `build.sbt` with other people who might not have that particular Scala version installed at 
`/path/to/scala/home/` or wherever.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly an answer, but a suggestion:

Unless you specify `retrieveManaged := true`, sbt keeps only one copy in `~/.sbt` which will be *shared among* all sbt projects. Because different projects can use different Scala versions, this approach is much better than pointing to an existing installation. If you have six projects using Scala 2.9.3, one using 2.9.2, ten using 2.10.0, and five using 2.10.3, sbt will just keep the four distinct Scala versions around, but not in multiple copies.